# Как поочерёдно удалять картинки

Tags: python, tkinter

При нажатии кнопки 1 должна убираться 1 спичка. При моём коде, удаляется только одна спичка.
Вот моя версия кода

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

root = Tk()
root.geometry("620x300")
root.configure(bg='gray')

def s1():
    canvas.delete(jid)

wbutt1 = Button(root, text="1",anchor=CENTER, command = s1, bg='DimGrey')
wbutt1.place(x=225, y=30)

i = 10
def i2():
    global i
    i = i + 40

canvas = Canvas(root, bg="gray", height=167, width=600)
canvas.pack(anchor='s', expand=1)
photo = PhotoImage(file="sptcka.png")
for r in range (0,11):
    i2()
    jid = canvas.create_image(i, 10, anchor='nw',image=photo)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Добавляйте новые спички в список, а не просто в переменную.

Comment: Или в словарь `jid[r]`, так как после завершения цикла в переменной `jid` будет последняя созданная на полотне картинка.

Comment: Извините, но немного не понял,  покажите на моём коде покажите на моём коде пожалуйста

Comment: @RevIk переменная jid у вас хранит ровно одно изображение, каждое последующее изображение перезатирает старое. А нужно сохранить все изображения. Для этого нужно создать пустой список до цикла, потом в цикле через append добавлять все изображения в него. Потом при удалении уже через pop вытаскивать изображение и удалять. Почитайте про списки в python.